# How to make pytest ignore a class named TestSomething?

Tags: python, pytest

I am working on a kind of test framework that happens to have classes named `TestSomething` of course. And I realized my tests are failing because pytest sees these classes as "something I need to instantiate and run!", as soon as imported. And this absolutely won't work.

```
import pytest
from package import TestSomethingClass
```

Is it possible to import such class from a pytest test file directly? Or should I indirectly use those via a fixture maybe?

The same problem applies to exceptions, as I would need to do something like

```
with pytest.raises(TestsSomethingError):
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Explicitly Disable

You're able to allow pytest to ignore this specific class by virtue of it starting with the word `Test`, by setting the  `__test__` flag to `False` within your conflicting class

```
class TestSomethingClass(object):
    __test__ = False

    def test_class_something(self, object):
        pass
```

**feature: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/pull/1561**

---

## Configuration File

We could also change the convention completely in your `pytest.ini` file and ignore all class names which start the word `Example`. But I don't advice this, as we could potentially encounter unintended consequences down the road.

```
#pytest.ini file
[pytest]
python_classes = !Example
```

---

## Pytest Conventions

- test prefixed test functions or methods outside of class
- test prefixed test functions or methods inside Test prefixed test classes (without an **init** method)

**Source: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/customize.html**

Comment: Perfect! I ended up using the configuration file option, which avoids injecting unit test related code in the codebase. Thanks :)